# Regarding ePub uploading?

Tags: objective-c

One of my clients wants a functionality to sync his ebook reader app of iphone with iTunes Store or App Store for downloading epubs or ebooks and want to put his epub and ebooks at itunes store or app store.He do not want maintain a server for this purpose.

Is it possible to upload epubs or ebooks on iTunes Store or App store?? If yes what is the process and how will sync the app for downloading the epubs and ebooks??

Thanks 
Anuj Saini

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with that. Seriously though its a closed shop and you will not be able to use app store functionality because Apple will not let you any more than you could walk into a chain supermarket and setup your own mini-mart inside.

Possibly the the app will be rejected on the duplicate functionality restriction anyway (iBooks does that)

As for getting their epubs on the Book Store apply to Apple. There will be a channel for that.